# Need explanation for the Debian Mirror Checker status page

Tags: debian, mirror-site

The [Debian Mirror Checker](http://ftp.de.debian.org/dmc/today/) provides status on Debian package mirror sites. The data is in a large table whose first couple of lines look like this:

```
R Host              T ftp-master time             TS Update ftp   http  rsync
1 debian.inhost.pro L Sun Mar 8 15:11:46 UTC 2015            .    Ok    .
1 ftp.ru.debian.org L Sun Mar 8 15:11:46 UTC 2015  7         Ok   Ok    Ok
```

What do these columns mean? For example, is a `.` (period) in the `rsync` column good or bad? What does it signify? If the `Update` column is checked, what does that mean?

Maybe someone can direct me to a page that has the documentation for this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right down at the bottom of the page [you linked to](http://ftp.de.debian.org/dmc/today/) is a Legend which explains that stuff

> **Legend**

```
HostPattern .
R        Ranking
.        Not advertised by this mirror
Ok       Accessible
A        Advertised
Update   Archive_update_in_progress file found
TS       Tracefile status
(T)ype   P: Push-Primary, S: Push-Secondary, L: Leaf, ?: not in DB (will be leaf, of course)
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I must say, that page is not easy to use.

Comment: It's amazing what you find when you bother to look. It took me about 15 seconds to find that information, most of which was spent scrolling to the bottom to look and see what was there.