# how do I get the Debian bookworm mirror at mirrors.kernel.org fixed?

Tags: debian, mirror-site

Given:

```
martind@stormy:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bookworm.list
deb http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/debian bookworm contrib
#deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian bookworm contrib
martind@stormy:~$
```

... downloading the package indexes fails:

```
martind@stormy:~$ sudo apt update
...
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/debian bookworm Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
martind@stormy:~$
```

Switch to the commented-out line and all is well.  (`contrib` isn't especially interesting but it is small, yet demonstrates the problem.)

The files at:

https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/debian/dists/bookworm/

... are far too small, compared to:

https://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/

(I'd be consistent and use ftp.us.debian.org but it fails certificate validation for me.)

They return a custom 404 page.  Could they be dangling symlinks?  It's not a problem shared with Debian's own mirrors or, to pick some that might be geographically close from Debian's list of other mirrors:

http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/debian/dists/bookworm/
http://mirrors.namecheap.com/debian/dists/bookworm/
http://mirror.cogentco.com/debian/dists/bookworm/

... so it seems to be specific to mirrors.kernel.org, although I suspect provoked by a change in Debian, because the onset was not long after the arrival of:

https://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian12.1/

I can certainly sympathize but:

https://www.kernel.org/category/contact-us.html

... feels like "talk to the hand, we can't deal with teh n00b5".

Does the presence of edge.kernel.org at:

http://ftp.de.debian.org/dmc/today/

... which I learned about from Stack Overflow suggesting I read [Need explanation for the Debian Mirror Checker status page](https://serverfault.com/questions/673878/need-explanation-for-the-debian-mirror-checker-status-page) before posting this, indicate that it's in some way a Debian-run mirror and that there might therefore be hope of getting attention by raising a Debian bug?  (mirrors.kernel.org redirects to mirrors.edge.kernel.org these days.)

I guess I'll have to switch to another mirror site, but that's a shame because mirrors.kernel.org has been reliable and quick for years.  The odd glitch or two, which might have come from upstream, has previously been fixed in a couple of days, far as I recall, whereas this problem has dragged on for a week now.  I doubt wailing into the void here will help but...

Comment: not sure why you'd think `mirrors.edge.kernel.org` is a Debian-run mirror

Comment: The problem went away the day I posted it here.